# QUARKUS - CXF Extension - Consume https/SOAP service

Tags: cxf, quarkus

I am trying to build a simple CXF client in Quarkus (2.16) using the extension quarkus-cxf and the service is exposed in remote https/SOAP. I have got the WSDL of the service and a valid the certificate .p12 to access to the service.

Does anyone have an example of a client similar to what I need to build? Or, can you give me some links I can refer to?

I found few examples of http/SOAP clients in Quarkus, but i can't find an example how to implement the https/SOAP CXF client with a .p12 certificate.

Thanks